# Variable scope problems with dictionaries

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, dictionary, scope

So I am creating a terminal program that allows you to create accounts and login/logout of them. Once you login successfully it returns a user session function and loops while asking the user to input commands. I want to create a dictionary of commands and map all the command to a function that does what I want that command to do. My problem is, some functions rely on figuring out the current user session, but the username variables scope is only in the user session function, so once the function is run from the dictionary I need to be able to get the currentuser variable and use it as an argument to the functions in the commands dictionary. I only posted the parts of my code relating to this problem. If you need to see the whole code, or have any questions please let me know. Thanks for your help.

```
commands = {
    "view mail": view_mail(),
    "send mail": send_mail(),
    "logout": True
}

def session(currentuser):
    print("Commands: view mail | send mail | logout")
    while True:
        option = input("> ")
        if option in commands:
            end_session = commands[option]
            if end_session:
                break
        else:
            print(option + " is not an option")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the functions when you declare the dictionary, try storing them in the declaration of `commands`:

```
commands = {
    "view mail": view_mail,
    "send mail": send_mail,
    "logout": lambda u: True
}
```

Pass in the username at runtime:

```
end_session = commands[option](username)
```

Edit:
So what if some of the functions take no arguments?  You could hack it with a dummy argument (like the `lambda` above) or, better, have all your functions with the signature: `def fun_name(*args):`

The `*args` is a common idiom in Python, and indicates parameter unpacking.  Thing is, it can be empty, or it can contain numerous arguments.

```
def multi(*args):
    p1, p2, p3 = args

def noargs(*args):
    pass

multi(1,2,3)
noargs()
```

Comment: plus one for using a lambda. I never thought of that at the moment.

Comment: now what if one of the commands doesn't take any arguments. or if one of the commands takes more than one argument. That's gonna be a problem.